# Express.js and AngularJS routing parameters

Tags: routes, angularjs, express

I'm trying to set up some routes with parameters in an AngularJS app backed by a node.js server using express. Node is set up to route everything that isn't explicitely found to a catch all:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(function(request, response)
{
    console.log("catch all");
    writeFile("/public/index.htm", request, response);
});
```

And Angular has routes defined with 0-2 parameters:

```
$routeProvider
.when("/",
{
    templateUrl: "home.htm"
})
.when("/otherpage",
{
    templateUrl: "otherpage.htm"
})  
.when("/otherpage/:Var1",
{
    templateUrl: "otherpage.htm"
})  
.when("/otherpage/:Var1/:Var2",
{
    templateUrl: "otherpage.htm"
})
.otherwise(
{
    templateUrl: "home.htm"
});

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

/otherpage works, but while /otherpage/123 hits the catch all (I can see the console message), it crashes in the browser. Nothing is rendered and then Chrome says that it has a problem (and IE renders nothing just sits there).

I can understand the parameter not being passed, but why isn't the route at least happening without it? What do I need to do to set up URL parameters with express.js and AngularJS?

You can download the project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5y32is1lf9yimx7/routing.zip), if you want to examine it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would highly recommend using Brian Fords excellent Angular-Express-Seed as your starting point. Check out https://github.com/btford/angular-express-seed. Being new to both Node and Angular, I've used this on my own project and found it to be invaluable.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I wasn't preceding my templateUrls with a foreslash. Changing them to this:

```
.when("/otherpage/:Var1/:Var2",
{
    templateUrl: "/otherpage.htm"
})
```

Worked perfectly.